# SeachView to be viewed in Toolbar and not in Actionbar

Tags: android, searchview

Hey guys i am trying to implement Seach in My App in which i added a search menu item in ToolBar. When i Click the Search icon it gives me this:

[image]

How Can i make it to be in The toolBar(yellow bar behind that?

My searchable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

My Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".ListLoaderActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/search" />
        </activity>
```

My Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            //Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Nothing to search for", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.about: {
                MyMessageDialog.displayMessage(ListLoaderActivity.this, "Stock Predictions");
                return true;
            }case R.id.search:{
                onSearchRequested();
                return true;
            }
            default: {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```